# OpenSSL PEM_read_bio_X509() function across different architectures

Tags: c++, ssl, arm, cross-platform

I have a certificate and I am using **PEM_read_bio_X509()** function to parse this certificate and using some other functions (ie: **X509_get_pubkey**) to extract required information from the certificate.

You can find the code block below that I am using. That code block is working well on an x86_64 architecture however the same code generates errors and not running. It seems there is a problem across different architecture, however I cannot find an appropriate solution.

The generated error string for ARM architecture is as following:

```
ErrorMessage: error:0906D064:lib(9):func(109):reason(100)
```

Looking to **pem.h** file, the equivalents for error codes are as following:

```
func(109):
# define PEM_F_PEM_READ_BIO                               109
reason(100):
# define PEM_R_BAD_BASE64_DECODE                          100
```

I am using the following code snippet to read from a buffer and extract a pointer to X509 structure:

```
BIO * bio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
BIO_write(bio, createdMemory, buffSize);
X509 * certificate = PEM_read_bio_X509(bio,NULL,0,NULL) ;
unsigned long errCode = ERR_peek_last_error();
char errBuffer[16384];
ERR_error_string_n(errCode, errBuffer, 16384);
std::string errBufferStr(errBuffer);
std::cout << "ErrorMessage: " << errBufferStr << std::endl;
```

Here `createdMemory` is a char array that holds the certificate content like:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
Certificate content encoded with base64
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

System Configuration:
ARM Side: 
3.14.38-6UL_ga+ge4944a5 #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Jun 14 15:05:40 EEST 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux
This is an imx6 Evaluation Kit, cross toolchain and the filesystem is generated using Yocto.

x86_64 Side: 
3.13.0-88-generic #135-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 8 21:10:42 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Any help will be appreciated.
Regards.

Comment: I'd suggest you shift your attention from the code to the content of your certificate on your ARM device. Chances are the file is genuinely corrupted/truncated in some way.

Comment: I've checked the md5sum of the two copies of files. They are the same. Problem still exists.

Comment: Hmm. Well, if I were you I would look at the openSSL sources for any hints on what might be wrong. crypto\evp\encode.c, EVP_DecodeUpdate() - that's what (I think) gives you the error you quoted.

Comment: I am going to look at the sources. Besides, I got the core dumps from architectures x86 and ARM and checked the buffers have the same content. So there is no error in reading from file, parsing and writing to buffer routines.